# use ConvexGeometry in npm version of THREE

Tags: javascript, npm, three.js

How can I use `ConvexGeometry` in the npm version of THREE?
it seems like it has been added in `r85`: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases

but  it's only code in the example folder as it seems.
is there a way to use it with npm THREE ?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
import 'three/examples/js/QuickHull';
import 'three/examples/js/geometries/ConvexGeometry';
import 'three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls';
```